# Correcting syntax on a Char counting function

Tags: c++, function, ifstream

Trying to create a function that will count the number of characters in a file.
Yet compiler is saying: comparison of constant -1 with expression of type
      'bool' is always true

I'm pretty sure that get() returns a -1 if there isn't anymore char to get.

```
int num_of_char(ifstream &file)
{
    int c, cnt = 0;
    ifstream chars;

    if((c == chars.get()) != -1)cnt++;
    return(cnt);
}
```

Comment: You want `c = chars.get()`, not `==`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to do like this:

```
int num_of_char(ifstream &file)
{
int c, cnt = 0;
ifstream chars;

if((c = file.get()) != -1)cnt++;
return(cnt);
}
```